# Merging files in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to merge 2 files. First file (`co60.txt`) contains only integer values and the second file (`bins.txt`) contains float numbers.

co60.txt:

```
11
14
12
14
18
15
18
9
```

bins.txt:

```
0.00017777777777777795
0.0003555555555555559
0.0005333333333333338
0.0007111111111111118
0.0008888888888888898
0.0010666666666666676
0.0012444444444444456
0.0014222222222222236
```

When I merge those two file with this code:

```
with open("co60.txt", 'r') as a:
    a1 = [re.findall(r"[\w']+", line) for line in a]
with open("bins.txt", 'r') as b:
    b1 = [re.findall(r"[\w']+", line) for line in b]
with open("spectrum.txt", 'w') as c:
    for x,y in zip(a1,b1):
        c.write("{} {}\n".format(" ".join(x),y[0]))
```

I get:

```
11 0
14 0
12 0
14 0
18 0
15 0
18 0
9 0
```

It appears that when I merge these 2 files, this code only merges round values of the file `bins.txt`.

How do I get that files merge like this:

```
11 0.00017777777777777795
14 0.0003555555555555559
12 0.0005333333333333338
14 0.0007111111111111118
18 0.0008888888888888898
15 0.0010666666666666676
18 0.0012444444444444456
9 0.0014222222222222236
```

Comment: Why do you need the RegEx?
Anyway, your problem is that your regex can't match the '.' character, consider using `[0-9\.]+` for pattern

Comment: could you please write an answer with correct code? i'm new to programing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @immortal, if you want to use regex then use -

```
b1 = [re.findall(r"[0-9\.]+", line) for line in b]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it without regex::

```
with open("co60.txt") as a, open("bins.txt") as b, \
    open("spectrum.txt", 'w') as c:
    for x,y in zip(a, b):
        c.write("{} {}\n".format(x.strip(), y.strip()))
```

Content of `spectrum.txt`:

```
11 0.00017777777777777795
14 0.0003555555555555559
12 0.0005333333333333338
14 0.0007111111111111118
18 0.0008888888888888898
15 0.0010666666666666676
18 0.0012444444444444456
9 0.0014222222222222236
```